# Проблема в установке Android Studio: "Error 216"

Tags: android, android-studio

Проблема в Android Studio Error-216 Как исправить ...Помогите  У меня 32 bit Windows 7

После установки Android Studio 2.2 (+jdk) При открытии снизу появляется такая строка... Что это за ошибка как ее исправить? Заранее спасибо Вроде все норм версия последняя винда стоит

> 32 Error:CreateProcess error=216, Версия "%1" не совместима с версией
>   Windows, работающей на этом компьютере. Проверьте сведения о системе,
>   чтобы узнать, какая версия программы x86 (32-разрядная) или x64
>   (64-разрядная) вам нужна, и получите ее у поставщика программного
>   обеспечения

Comment: Скорее всего у вас Android SDK  64-битный

Comment: Android скачивался отсюда: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html там нигде и не указывается битность

Answer (score 1):

Ответ с en SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624369/android-studio-error-errorcreateprocess-error-216-this-version-of-1-is-not-c

1. Установите JDK1.8 (для 32 разрядных систем)
2. В **AndroidStudio** `File->Project Structure->SDK Location`, выбирите директорию, в которую установили JDK. По умолчанию, **AndroidStudio** андрой студио использует встроенный JDK, который "глючит" на 32 разрядных операционных системах.
3. Нажмите Ok.